# Projecting line into the future

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

have a calculation (intraday on 30 min chart) whose result should be displayed as a line and the last calculation as a line into the future (x-axis).

For the line I use ("out" is the result of the calculation):

```
var line last_line = na
if out[1] != out
    if not na(last_line)
        line.set_extend(last_line, extend.none)
        line.set_x2(last_line, bar_index + offset)
    last_line := line.new(bar_index + offset, out, bar_index+1+offset, out, extend = extend.right, width=width, color=color)
```

I get the error message:
“The 'timeframe' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects”

The indicator is called up with:
indicator(……., timeframe="D", overlay = true, timeframe_gaps=true, max_bars_back = 3000)

What could be the reason for the error message? How can I fix it? Or can I draw the line differently?

Answer (score 0):

Tradingview usually cannot automatically do the MTF analysis when you have drawings.

In order to make it happen, you need to remove `timeframe="D", timeframe_gaps=true` part from your `indicator()` call and do your own MTF analysis by using the `request.security()` function.